# SQL query update with two WHERE

Tags: php, sql-server, database

I's posible update table with two where?

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name ='test' 
WHERE code='605';
```

Becouse sql syntax with two WHERE not exist? How to solve?

Comment: Yes it is. `UPDATE table_name SET column_name ='test' WHERE code='605' AND somethingother='something';`. You should add `AND` in between the two conditions and not **two WHERE**

Comment: Your question is not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AND` or `OR`:

Using `AND`:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name ='test' 
WHERE code='605'
  AND Col='someval'
```

When you use `AND`, it will update the table **only if both** conditions are satisfied.

Using `OR`:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name ='test' 
WHERE code='605'
  OR Col='someval'
```

When you use `OR`, it will update the table **if any one** of the conditions are satisfied.

**EDIT:**

For joining another table in UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE T1
SET column_name='test'
FROM table_name T1 JOIN
     another_table T2 on T1.PK=T2.FK
WHERE T1.code='605' 
  AND T2.Column_from_other_table='someval'
```

Comment: UPDATE table_name
SET column_name ='test' 
WHERE code='605'
  AND Column_from_another table='someval' posible?

Comment: @user3686909: Ofcourse, but you need to join those tables for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can add some expressions to your where clause:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name ='test' 
WHERE code='605' or code = '907' or code = '534';
```

That query will update all rows with that codes.